# Smooth Scroll On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code for scroll on an anchor link. It works one time and if click on anchor again it is not working.

```
$("#erly").on("click", function() {
    $(".table-responsive").scrollLeft(0);
});
$("#late").on("click", function() {
    $(".table-responsive").scrollLeft(50);
});
```

Comment: can you please post your html and css, to better understand your concern

Comment: Can please more elaborate your question or post some code.!!

Answer (score 0):

You may try unbinding the previous event handlers, like this.

```js
           $("#erly").unbind().on("click", function() {
             $(".table-responsive").scrollLeft(0);
           });

           $("#late").unbind().on("click", function() {
             $(".table-responsive").scrollLeft(50);
           });
```

```css
  div.table-responsive {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 3px solid #666;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  p {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a id="erly" href="#1">Early</a>
  <br />
  <a id="late" href="#2">Late</a>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1>lalala</h1>
    <p>Hello 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1>lalala</h1>
    <p>Hello 2</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I just put together an example that works. Not sure if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 early_late">
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="pull-left">
        <a id="erly" class="erlier" onclick="scrollWin2()"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left span_left"></span> Earlier</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pull-right"  onclick="scrollWin()">
        <a id="late">Late <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right span_right"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
function scrollWin() {
    document.getElementById('scroll').scrollBy(100 , 0);
}
function scrollWin2() {
    document.getElementById('scroll').scrollBy(-100 , 0);
}
```